# Get email address from directory with Full name in appmaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have selected a user name from dropdown list values are from Directory, I would like to get that user's email address from the directory, I have tried in this way but it didn't work, could someone please help.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0xPt.jpg)

`\\ client script

```
function getEmailAddress(Name)
{


 var Email =  EmailAddress(Name);

 return Email;

}
```

\\Server Script

```
function EmailAddress(Name)
{

var query = app.models.Directory.newQuery();
 query.filters.PrimaryEmail._contains.substring(Name);

 return query.run();

}`
```

Comment: Since your dropdown is using the Directory model have you considered using the UserPicker widget instead and then binding the value field of the UserPicker to datasource.item.Emailaddress? It seems that the UserPicker might be much simpler to implement instead of a dropdown, especially since it will give you suggestions from the directory as soon as you start typing in a name. Otherwise, the only thing I can tell you at the moment is to call a server function from the client you have to do google.script.run.YourFunction().

Comment: Thank you Markus, it is working with UserPicker widget but it is not working by calling server script as my function which is written to filter email address using employee name is not going through properly, do you have any idea how to modify my script to get respective email address of employee name

Comment: Which part exactly is not working. I tested this somewhat in my application and looking at your Image when you bind a client function to your dropdown value, it gives me an 'undefined' error. In order to provide more helpful guidance I would need to know your dropdown 'options' binding. I think that you are possibly overthinking this by using client/server scripts. Presumably your dropdown has options of directory names? If that is the case you should just use the dropdown onValueEdit event to assign the chosen name's email address to your email address field.

Comment: Yes Markus, options in dropdown are from directory and full name of employees

Comment: can you please help me how to get chosen name's email address

Comment: I would still suggest to using bindings. So it looks like your form widget will have it's datasource set to something like this 'MyDatasource (create)' then your dropdown bindings should be as follows: options - models.Directory.datasources.Directory.items..PrimaryEmail, names - models.Directory.datasources.Directory.items..FullName, value - datasource.item.EmployeeEmail. You will want to adjust the value binding to what your actual field is called.

Comment: thank you so much Markus, I tried using scripts I got solution which I pasted below

Answer (score 0):

I got an solution for this, when I choose a person name from dropdown this gives person's email address automatically into email address field.

```
//Widget binding

setEmailAddress(@widget, @widget.root.descendants.EmployeeName.value)

//Client script

function setEmailAddress(widget, Fullname)
{
  google.script.run           
      .withSuccessHandler(function(result){
       widget.value = result;
      })
     .withFailureHandler(function(error){
      error = "unable to load user's mail id";
      console.error(error);
      }) .getEmailAddress(Fullname);
    }
  }

//Server script

function getEmailAddress(Fullname){

  var directoryQuery = app.models.Directory.newQuery();
  directoryQuery.filters.FullName._equals = Fullname;
  var person = directoryQuery.run()[0];
  return person.PrimaryEmail;
}
```